# Web - to - PSTN call using SINCH-REST-API

Tags: javascript, jquery, sinch, android-sinch-api, sinch-verification

## Hello All,

Kindly find the points below;

a. In my project, I want to call a phone number (PSTN) from a web-application (in PHP) and when the owner of the number picks up, I will play an audio file for him -- No conversation needed.

b. I spoke to Sinch team,  they said SINCH-REST-API can do it and gave me the code below;

```
https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest#Callouts
 [POST] https://callingapi.sinch.com/v1/callouts
 {
 "method" : "ttsCallout",
 "ttsCallout" :
 {
 "cli" : "46000000000",
 "destination" : { "type" : "number", "endpoint" : "46000000001" },
 "domain" : "pstn",
 "custom" : "customData",
 "locale" : "en-US",
 "text" : "#href[http://www.thehotline.co/content/prompts/v2/1greeting_b.wav]"
 }
 }
```

c.) I am very new to SINCH-REST-API and consuming REST-API using javascripts OR Jquery...

Please, if anybody can give me a sample code on how to use the idea from SINCH-team and achieve my goal, I will appreciate..

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You have to create application key and secret then Use cURL to call api
for more info about cURL:http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php and also detail info about sinch api visit:https://www.sinch.com/docs/

```
  //application call
  $ApplicationKey = "XXXXXXX";
  $ApplicationSecret = "YYYYYYY";
  $usernameAndPassword = $ApplicationKey . ":" . $ApplicationSecret;
  $Authorization = base64_encode ( $usernameAndPassword );

   $curl = curl_init();

   curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://callingapi.sinch.com/v1/callouts",    
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\r\n    \"method\" : \"ttsCallout\",\r\n    \"ttsCallout\" :\r\n    {\r\n        \"cli\" : \"46000000000\",\r\n        \"destination\" : { \"type\" : \"number\", \"endpoint\" : \"460000000001\" },\r\n        \"domain\" : \"pstn\",\r\n        \"custom\" : \"customData\",\r\n        \"locale\" : \"en-US\",\r\n      \"text\" : \"http://www.thehotline.co/content/prompts/v2/1greeting_b.wav\"\r\n    }\r\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization:Basic $Authorization",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
  $err = curl_error($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: i did not receive the call